# mypy typing leeds to unexpected traceback

Tags: python, mypy

I'm trying to use a work-around for the problems described in [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5485) GitHub issue (*"Class with function fields incorrectly thinks the first argument is self"*).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Any, Iterable, List

T = TypeVar("T")

# See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5485


@dataclass
class Box(Generic[T]):
    inner: T

    @property
    def unboxed(self) -> T:
        return self.inner
```

I run into a traceback like this, though:

However, upon ***importing***  (only(!) ) the code above from another module I run into a traceback like this:

```
(py) sugarline:~/src/oss/ormsnack write-compile-eval
Traceback (most recent call last):
[.....]
  File "/Users/jacob/src/oss/ormsnack/ormsnack/ng_desc.py", line 8, in <module>
    from kingston.kind import Box  # type: ignore
  File "kingston/kind.py", line 12, in <module>
AttributeError: attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects is not writable
```

Googling only lands me in old bugs that seem to have gone stale, though (https://bugs.python.org/issue38099, https://github.com/man-group/arctic/issues/17), etc.

Is anyone able to figure out a work-around?

Comment: If I try your code on [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/) I don't get this error. Which Python and mypy versions do you have?

Comment: Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  7 2020, 14:06:47) [Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)] on darwin] MyPy latest HEAD from https://github.com/python/mypy

Comment: You are right about the Playground, yes. Curios. I also noticed another thing: I can only reproduce the error if I import the code from another module (`ormsnack.ng_desc` in this case). When I execute the above in a file using regular `python kind.py`, the problem doesn't appear.

Comment: The mypy playground doesn't run your code. It just runs mypy. Errors that happen when you run your code won't happen on the mypy playground.

Comment: That traceback suggests you're not really importing what you posted. Line 12 is blank in what you posted, and the lack of source code for that line in the traceback is suspicious. You may accidentally be using the wrong file.